# Send an email to my work's email server with JavaMail

Tags: java, email, server

I have searched through many other posts on here with users with similar problems but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
package testingstuff;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World");


    final String user = "my work ID";
    final String pw = "my work Password";

    Properties props = new Properties(); 



    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "server I got from our outlook app");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pw);
              }
            });

    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        String from = "kevin.camacho@company.com";
        String to = "my.colleague@company.com";
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject("TEST");
        msg.setText("TESTING");

        //Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        //trans.connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 25, user, pw);
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println("done");
}

}
```

I am using java 1.8, JavaMail reports that it is version 1.4.7

Here is the output from the session debug:

```
Hello World
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7

DEBUG: getProvider() returning   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "[my work email server]", port 587, isSSL false

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: [my work email server], port: 587;
```

nested exception is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

done

The email server that I got that I am using is from out outlook app. I went to account settings, selected my account and selected change. This opens up a window with the config for the email and it contains the server address.

Comment: I tried doing that before and it did not work also. i was sending it from a work network so it was being blocked. i suggest emailing to a private gmail or something and seeing if that works

Comment: Maybe the port number may cause a problem. Try "80" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, just put in the username,password,to,from,host

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
          String username = "";
          String password = "";
          String to = "";
          String from = "";
          String host = "";

          Properties properties = System.getProperties();


          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", username);
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", password);
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true"); 
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try{
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

             message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

             messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);




             message.setContent(multipart);



             message.saveChanges();
             Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
             transport.connect(host, username, password);
             transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
             transport.close();
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }
}



}
```

Comment: Hello, it still seems to not work.
I think it may be that I possibly have the wrong port or I may require some extra security measures to be able to get in. I've emailed the IT support at work asking them what credentials and settings I need to be able to make this work. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I had the wrong host.